# Bootstrap shown.bs.tab event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I'm using the [Flexy template](http://the8guild.com/themes/html/flexy/v1.7/stylesPage.html) (using bootstrap) and I can't get the shown.bs.tab event on tab to work.

I've managed to make it work on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st8h6a92/).

Here is the code I use in my template that produce nothing :

```
<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a id="tab1" href="#chart1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab2" href="#chart2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="chart1">Tab 1 Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="chart2">Tabe 2 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      alert(e.target.href);
    })
  });
</script>
```

What can I miss ? If I copy/paste this code on the Flexy code it doesn't work. What are the steps to understand what is wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was more **a rails-related one**.

I ended up by removing one by one every piece of code since the issue was not there in the raw template as @KyleMit says.

Whenever I remove the line `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` from my application.js file the issue disappears !

The issue was that I was requiring both `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-sprockets`. I should have require just one of them but **not both**.

Answer (score 31):

[Bootstrap tab events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) are based off the `.nav-tabs` elements, not the `.tab-content` elements.  So in order to tap into the show event, you need the element with an href that is pointed towards `#tab1`, not the `#tab1` content element itself.

So instead of this:

```
$('#tab1').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log("tab1");
});
```

Do this instead:

```
$('[href=#tab1]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log("tab1");
});
```

Or, to capture all of them, just do this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.href);
})
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.href);
})
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a id="tab1" href="#chart1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab2" href="#chart2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="chart1">Tab 1 Content</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="chart2">Tabe 2 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ! I understand what you said but unfortunately it still doesn't work, there must be something else somewhere ... I created a test page so you can take a look if you want : http://ow.ly/NtxpL

Comment: Though we see the shown event in Firebug... http://hpics.li/42cc757
But it is never fired

Comment: @StéphaneJ., here's an example of the [exact code I provided working on your exact page](http://i.imgur.com/0RTyWOH.gif).  In general, please try to avoid representing issues on your own custom test pages.  Instead, try to abstract your problem down into small sections of reproducible code instead of providing a link to your own web page with tons of code. **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).

Comment: thank you for you quality answer. The problem is that I know this is supposed to work, but not in my code. Anyway, your example helped me, I will try to understand the differences between the raw template and mine.

Comment: I don't know if it can be the problem but I'm using Rails

Answer (score 14):

If the Tab is dynamic in anyway try using

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.href);
})
```

Comment: Yeap that worked but i don't understand why this example : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#events doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

In my case, there was a conflict between Jquery and Bootstrap.

I solved the problem with jQuery.noConflict(). See below!

I hope that helps!

```
// Issue @ tabs toggle 
jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.href);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not sure why... Can you please explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I faces was that I had 2 sets of tabs on my page. and I had already bound the 1st tab set with

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.href);
})
```

For the 2nd tab set also i had defined the same way.. but I had assigned an id to the ul and bound the click element as:

```
  $('#tabId > li > a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      console.log(e.target.href);
    })
```

The 1st tab was working here but the 2nd wouldn't work. I then figured it out and assigned id's to both uls.. now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's simple and listen to the only Tab you need :

```
$('a[href="#idTab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
 `console.log('this tab is shown');`//or do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bootstrap event `'shown.bs.tab'` failed to fire using the above solutions. So, I decided to enable tabbable tabs via javaScript.

```js
    const adjustColumnHeaders = () => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
                .columns.adjust()
                .responsive.recalc();
        }, 200);
    };

    const boostrapTabs = $('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]');
    boostrapTabs.click(function () {
        $(this).tab("show");
        adjustColumnHeaders();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        const tabLink = $(`a[href=${'"' + window.location.hash + '"'}]`);
        if(tabLink.length) tabLink.trigger( "click" );
    });
```

Then in your HTML markup, rename `data-toggle="tab"` to `data-bs-toggle="tab"`.
I.e:

```html
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tab-employees">
      Employees
   </a>
 </li>
```